# GAE Datastore search not working on local development instance (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

My local instance of Java Google App Engine seems to index search documents just fine, but started throwing an exception when running a search. Code snippet and exception included. TIA!

Code for searching :

```
QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
            .setLimit(500)
            .build();
    String queryString = searchStr;
    Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build(queryString);

    IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName(projectName + "Search").build(); 
    Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);

    Results<ScoredDocument> results = null;

    try {

        results = index.search(query);

    } catch (SearchException e) {

    }
```

Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchServicePb$ListDocumentsResponse$Builder.addDocument(SearchServicePb.java:13298)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.listDocumentsForApp(LocalSearchService.java:527)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.getFieldTypes(LocalSearchService.java:710)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.searchForApp(LocalSearchService.java:564)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.search(LocalSearchService.java:547)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:525)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:479)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:456)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:493)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:490)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: This is not a question; it's a bug report. It would be better to file the bug report on the App Engine external issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3  We are not trying to be difficult. We actually tried to post a reply here, but it was removed by the Stack Exchange site guardians.

Comment: If it had been a while since you had indexed those documents, please remove the old indexed documents and index them again to see if that fixes it. There was a bug fix a while ago that could be related. Please let us know if reindexing solves the problem.